# Single shared session for multiple Spring Boot microservices in Redis

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, redis, microservices, spring-session

I have several separated Spring Boot microservices. Sessions are created separately for every microservice (and their instances). I have Spring Session involved, that helps with creating a single session for any number of instances of a microservice, which is helpful. I am wondering is it possible to share the common single session somehow for the bunch of these microservices and their instances upon a login into a dedicated auth module, for example. Without any oauth, sso and additional software, simply sharing a session among them?

Comment: If you share the sessionid through cookies or headers (which is also explained int he documentation of Spring Session).

Answer (score 0):

A reverse proxy, e.g. Nginx, in front of all micro services establishes session with a user’s browser and passes session header with each request from the browser to the micro services.

Comment: Tried this. Had to setup location /app1 {
 proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/app1;
 proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
}
location /app2 {
 proxy_pass http://localhost:8180/app2;
 proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
}
but it did not help. Every app requires its own login

Comment: Now your requests are pre-authenticated and you can remove existing session setup in the micro-services. You can simply use sessionId from the proxy to create/access session data in Redis or elsewhere. However, the heavy lifting of session creation now has to be done in the proxy.

Comment: The only idea is to utilize a common header behing the Nginx proxy and authenticate other microservices against a dedicated auth microservices, establishing for him a single session responsibility

Comment: There is a downside to a shared sessionId - any service can call any service using this sessionId.